# Is it possible to write a JS function with no access to global variables?

Tags: javascript, global-variables

For better knowledge of what a function is using, etc.
Might also be faster for variable lookups if not accessing the global scope?

Suppose I have:

```
a = 5;
b = 5;
```

in the global scope.  Is it possible to wrap the function below such that

```
function go() {
   console.log(a);
}
```

would not have access to "a" and the global namespace and return

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined
```

Comment: Yes, *of course* it's possible. In fact, most functions ideally *shouldn't* access global variables. What's the question here?

Comment: @AlexisKing: I think the question is whether it is possible to make some code run in a context where it not just *does not*, but *cannot* access global variables.

Comment: @icktoofay Ah, yes, that makes a little more sense. Sorry for my misunderstanding.

Comment: Although it's not completely supported you may want to see about [let statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) for ECMA6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to completely prevent access to global variables. That said, you *can* provide it a *different* set of global variables: namely, run it in an `iframe`. This isn’t bulletproof, though, since it could then just use `window.parent` to access the global variables of the parent.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The example below is straight from [MDN eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval).

You could try this *IF* you could wrap your entire codebase in a single wrapper function so that all your objects and functions fall into local scope. (I am not sure how practicable this is but it works in Chrome and Firefox)

```
(function() {
  var x = 2, y = 4;
  function range(a,b){return [a,b];}
  console.log("DIRECT", eval("x + y"), eval("range(3,4)"));  // Direct call, uses local scope, result is 6
  var geval = eval;
  console.log("INDIRECT", geval("x + y"), geval("range(3,4)")); // Indirect call, uses global scope, throws ReferenceError because `x` is undefined
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that no matter what the current scope is, there is always a way to get to the global object:

```
let ref_to_global = (function(){
  return this;
}).call(null);
```

Then one can access any property of the global object directly:

```
let value = ref_to_global["a"];
```

This means there is no way to make global scope inaccessible, if that was a question.

Comment: Wanna bet? https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-glitter-bmmb5m?file=/src/index.js
Please let me know if you (or anyone) finds a way to break out of this.